# error when unpickling a class from its constructor

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to implement a class (ideally a singleton) for which the state should be restored using cPickle mechanism at initialization stage. To do so I wrote the following snippet:

```
import cPickle
import collections

class Test(collections.OrderedDict):

    path = "test.cp"

    def __init__(self):

        self.path = "test.cp"

        collections.OrderedDict.__init__(self)
        try:
            f = open(Test.path,"rb")
        except IOError:
            return
        else:
            ud = cPickle.load(f)
            self.update(ud)
            f.close()

    def save(self):

        f = open(Test.path,"wb")
        cPickle.dump(self,f)
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    t.save()
    t1 = Test()
```

Running that snippet produces the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\pellegrini\Bureau\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    t1 = Test()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\pellegrini\Bureau\test.py", line 18, in __init__
    ud = cPickle.load(f)
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)', <class '__main__.Test'>, ([],))
```

When inheriting from a `dict` instead of a `collections.OrderedDict` this works. From other similar posts, this may have something to do with `__reduce__` method but I do not understand why and how ?

Would you have any idea about how to solve this problem ?

thanks a lot

Eric

Comment: Technically, there are no "constructors" as such in Python. Just an initialization method.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the OrderedDict has its own way of serialization.

```
def __init__(self, *args):

    self.path = "test.cp"

    collections.OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args)
```

try this and you get a recursion problem because pickle uses `__init__`.

An error free solution is:

```
import cPickle
import collections

class Test(collections.OrderedDict):

    path = "test.cp"

    def __init__(self, *args):

        self.path = "test.cp"

        collections.OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args)
        if not args:
            try:
                f = open(Test.path,"rb")
            except IOError:
                return
            else:
                ud = cPickle.load(f)
                self.update(ud)
                f.close()

    def save(self):

        with open(Test.path,"wb") as f:
            cPickle.dump(self,f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    t.save()
    t1 = Test()
```

**Singleton**

```
import pickle
import collections

_Test_singleton = None

class Test(collections.OrderedDict):

    path = "test.cp"

    def __new__(self, *args, **kw):
        global _Test_singleton
        if _Test_singleton is not None:
            return _Test_singleton
        _Test_singleton = collections.OrderedDict.__new__(self, *args, **kw)
        _Test_singleton.load()
        return _Test_singleton

    def __init__(self, *args):
        collections.OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args)

    def load(self):
        try:
            f = open(self.path,"rb")
        except IOError:
            return
        else:
            try:
                ud = pickle.load(f)
            finally:
                f.close()
            self.update(ud)

    def save(self):
        with open(self.path,"wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self,f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    t.save()
    t1 = Test()
    assert t is t1
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding `with` statements while at it. After all people will probably copy-paste your answer.

Comment: added a with statement. Your design is okay. Maybe you can split loading and initialization. That would be my suggestion. It also depends on what you want to achieve. Do you need a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or a state that can be [saved and loaded across running programs](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/mousemove/blob/master/mousemove/config.py)?

Comment: you right I should definitely use more often the with statement. I think that I really need a Singleton in the sense that I need an instance that must be instantiated once and only once (e.g. at the module level) and accessed thereafter by some other part of my application.